# php concatenate if condition array line

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a line in php like this:

```
if ($line[3]<=12)
```

And now I need to add new condition while keeping the old one.
Something like this, but is not working:

```
if ($line[3]<=12|$line[10]<1)
```

Could you please help?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic question dude. Have a look on logical operators in PHP.

If you want ONE of the conditions to be valid:

```
if ($line[3]<=12 || $line[10]<1)
```

If both conditions must be valid:

```
if ($line[3]<=12 && $line[10]<1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry. I searched but not on logical operators.

Comment: Not a problem. There is also a single pipe operator in PHP learn about bitwise operators ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the correct [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
if ($line[3] <= 12 || $line[10] < 1)
```